# Merge with primary key violation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a file based import thingy where the users can post files to be imported in the database. New records are inserted and records with an already existing Id are updated.

After posting a file with 
ID NAME
5 Silly

they can correct this by posting a new file with 
ID NAME
5 Sally

I have a bulk insert (C# windows service) of the file into a bulk table (Sql Server Azure v12). The files can contain millions of rows so I'd like to avoid iterating through rows. After the bulk insert i have a SP that does a merge update / insert and updates already existing rows and inserts new ones.

The problem I've come across is when the users post a new record and a correction of the same record in the same file. I get a PRIMARY KEY VIOLATION on the target table.

Is there a nice way to solve this?

Here's an example:

`--drop table #bulk
--drop table #target
create table #bulk(
id int,
name varchar(10)
)`

insert into #bulk values (1,'John')
insert into #bulk values (2,'Sally')
insert into #bulk values (3,'Paul')
insert into #bulk values (4,'Gretchen')
insert into #bulk values (5,'Penny')
insert into #bulk values (5,'Peggy')

create table #target(
id int not null,
name varchar(10),
primary key (id))

merge #target as target
using(select id, name from #bulk) as bulktable
on target.id = bulktable.id
when matched then update
set target.name = bulktable.name
when not matched then
insert(id, name) values (bulktable.id, bulktable.name);

Comment: 5 is a duplicate ID in #bulk with different Name. What would determine which Name should end up in #target

Comment: The last name should end up in target. Originally it was believed that the updates should come in a separate later file and if that's the case it works. The first record is inserted and the later record with the same id is treated as an update. Now though there is a requirement that both new record and an update of the same record should be able to come in the same file.
In the example the "Penny" record is the new one and the "Peggy" record, both with id 5 which is expected, is a correction of the previous one.

Comment: there is no such thing as the last name within the same ID, you need something to order by, otherwise you can't be sure it is the last name, You could have a column in the #bulk table that autoincrement to determine the last inserted value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle the latest value for name.

You need a new create script for #bulk

```
CREATE TABLE #bulk
(
  row_id int identity(1,1),
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)
```

This is the script you can use with the new bulk table:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    id, name, 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by row_id desc) rn
    FROM #bulk
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT id, name
  FROM CTE
  WHERE rn = 1
)
MERGE #target as target
USING CTE2 as bulktable
on target.id = bulktable.id
WHEN matched and 
 not exists(SELECT target.name except SELECT bulktable.name)
 -- this will handle null values. Otherwise it could simply have been: 
 -- matched and target.name <> bulktable.name
THEN update
SET target.name = bulktable.name
WHEN not matched THEN
INSERT(id, name) VALUES (bulktable.id, bulktable.name);
```